# How to get Last xx item from XML file with Xpath() query in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

How can I get last added 5 item's node from my XML file with Xpath ?

This is not what I want, it gives first 5 item, I want to get last 5 item:

`XPath="/newsSection/news[position()<=5]`

Comment: i have found my solution ,

Answer is XPath="/newsSection/news[position()>last()-5]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess:

```
XPath="/newsSection/news[position()>last()-5]
```

Comment: ah yes we r thinking same thing :)